# what does [self self] mean in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I was just reading some source code of https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit, and saw this

```
    +(void) initialize {

  if(!_sharedNetworkQueue) {
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
      _sharedNetworkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
      [_sharedNetworkQueue addObserver:[self self] forKeyPath:@"operationCount" options:0 context:NULL];
      [_sharedNetworkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:6];

    });
  }            
}
```

what does that [self self] mean here?

Comment: My first guess is that it points to the meta class of self. Perhaps someone can confirm if this is true? More info on meta classes of ObjC here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html Also read the following: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html (`Objective-C uses metaclasses for practical goals like class methods, but otherwise tends to hide metaclasses. For example, [NSObject class] is identical to [NSObject self]`)

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs: Nope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-self` is a method [defined in the `NSObject` *protocol*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/self). It returns the receiver, that is, the object you send the message `self` to. If you do `[a self]`, you get `a` back, and yes, if you do `[self self]` (or `self.self`), you indeed get `self` back.

It may be useful in key-value paths where you are supposed to append a new component, but intend to observe the entire object, like in Cocoa Bindings. I don't see any application of this in the code you posted, but it may be the case that proxies adopt `self` differently, to point to the proxy itself, rather than the remote/forwarded object.

Answer (score 8):

It is the same as `self`, only a redundant call .

```
[self self] // ---> Same object of self
```